# navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a navigator statefulwidget

Tags: button, flutter, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

I am working on the Flutter code that follows. I have issues with the second button called "Regitrese". Every place I have looked work with statelesswidgets so I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried changing the void to put on it home: MyHomePage() and put MyHomePage to statefull instead of taking the statefull from MyApp bus it shows a mistake Missing concrete implementation of StatefulWidget.createState. I am not sure how is it supposed to go. Can you make a button work in a StatefulWidget? Is there a trick I am not seeing?

```
void main()=> runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
 @override
   State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
     return new MyHomePage();
   }
}

class MyHomePage extends State<MyApp>{
 final TextEditingController rutController = TextEditingController();
 final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
 var _rut, _password;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new MaterialApp(
   home: new Scaffold(
    body: new Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: this.rutController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Rut',
              hintText: 'eg. 154683265',
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  onPressed: () {
                    rutController.clear();
                  }
                )
            ),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: this.passwordController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Contraseña',
              hintText: 'Contraseña',
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                    onPressed: () {
                      passwordController.clear();
                    },
                )
            ),
            obscureText: true,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              loginButton(rut: this.rutController.text, password: this.passwordController.text);
            },
            child: Text('Login'),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.push(
                 context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(builder(context)=>SelectUserPage())
              )
            },
            child: Text('Registrese'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
}
}

class SelectUserType extends StatelessWidget{
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return new Container(
   child: new Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          //Do something
        },
        child: Text(''),
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          //Do something
        },
        child: Text(''),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing is that you need to access a context below the `MaterialApp` widget that adds the `Navigator` to the tree. If you look at your code the `context` is above it.

One way to solve it is to move a part of the tree to another widget.

Or you can use a `Builder` around your button or around the `Column` as in the following code:

```
      Builder(
        builder: (context) => RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => SelectUserType()));
              },
              child: Text('Registrese'),
            ),
      ),
```

Comment: you made my day :)